# Problema con estilos en formulario creado con ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: html5, css3, asp.net-mvc-5

Estoy creando un formulario utilizando tecnologías MVC de Microsoft. Básicamente es un `<div>` que se dividen para tener dos columnas y ahí poner las etiquetas y controles. El problema es que la caja de texto del `Email` sale desalineada.

Este es el formulario:

[image: Fromulario]

Este es el código con la herramienta Visual Studio:

[image: Código]

Y esta es la forma de cómo se renderea en Chrome:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguna idea del por qué esté pasando esto?

Comment: Sería mucho más fácil poder ayudarte si crearas un código que pudiéramos probar. Con unas capturas de pantalla es muy difícil adivinar cual pueden ser las causas del error.

Comment: Debe falta un estilo, ya que esa caja de texto se ve cuadrada, pero todas las demas redondas. Podria incluir el codigo fuente de su html y sus css, en lugar de las imagenes, asi es mas facil para nosotros poder ayudarte :)

Comment: El código se renderea a partir de la tecnología de Visual Studio, ¿conocen alguna página dónde pueda subir mis páginas y probarlo?

Comment: Creo que es porque en el campo del email te está metiendo entre la capa div y el input un span y puede que por eso se pierda la relación de estilos

Answer (score 0):

Una forma práctica y efectiva de crear este tipo de alineación es agregando todos estos elementos dentro de una tabla, asi no tienes que preocuparte porque la tabla organiza de forma automática los elementos que la componen. Seria algo asi:

```
<table>
    <tr> <td>Nombre</td> <td> <input type="text" size="30"> </td> </tr>
    <tr> <td>Apellido Materno</td> <td> <input type="text" size="30"> </td> </tr>
</table>
```

Y asi sucesivamente. Espero te sirva.